# Getting error ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Tags: oracle, plsql, clob

I am getting

> **ORA-06502**: PL/SQL: numeric or value error in below code:

```
record_state := record_state || 'Inserting record Entry for student: ' || 
                roll_no || ' for date: ' || To_Char(admission_date,'yyyymmdd') ||
                ' @ ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') || CHR(10);
```

Below are the datatypes:

```
roll_no        - NUMBER(10,0)
admission_date - TIMESTAMP(6)
record_state   - CLOB
```

Comment: Have you tried removing expressions one by one till you find the problematic one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `to_clob` to convert string to clob and then you can concat two clobs as following:

```
record_state := record_state || 
                to_clob(
                        'Inserting record Entry for student: ' || roll_no || ' for date: ' || To_Char(admission_date,'yyyymmdd') || ' @ ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') || CHR(10)
                       );
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

if you have lob objects, i would suggest to use a [`DBMS_LOB`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS600) library.

```
DECLARE
  record_state  CLOB;  
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(record_state);  

  -- here you should make sure that the string is not too long (max 32K), otherwise the concatenation with pipes will not work. There will be an exception.
  DBMS_LOB.append (record_state , 'Inserting record Entry for student: ' || roll_no || ' for date: ' || To_Char(admission_date,'yyyymmdd') || ' @ ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') || CHR(10)); 

  -- do more operations
  dbms_lob.freetemporary(record_state);

END ;
/
```